Add 'Expected result' after steps in test cases in CSV file for Allure TestOps
Is it possible to add 'Expected result' after test case steps in CSV file?
enter image description here
I was try to edit Scenario like that:

Step
Expected result: Result
And i was try use some special chars:
Step*Result
Step/Result
Step//Result

